# pandas displaying one column's value in the order of top score

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data like

| deviceType | category | date | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | soccer | 07012022 | 10 |
| A | baseball | 07012022 | 8 |
| B | basketball | 07012022 | 9 |
| A | soccer | 07022022 | 9 |

and I would like to convert it to

| category | A | B | C...(device types so on) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | soccer | basketball |  |
|  | baseball |  |  |

which displays category values under each device type in descending order of average of that category scores (soccer is above baseball for device type A as its average score, 9.5, is higher than average score of baseball, 8)

I was trying this with using groupby with two columns (deviceType and category), but I couldn't figure out how to put one column's value under another.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: it looks like some `pivot` or `reshape`

Comment: what did you try with `groupby`? You could show code in question. And it would be simpler if you would put data as code - ie. converted to dictionary `df.to_dict()` - so we could copy data and use in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `gropby('device')` later work with every group separatelly to create `Series` with devide as `name`, and concatenate with other columns.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'device': ['A', 'A','B','A','C'], 
    'category': ['soccer','basketball','basketball','soccer','tenis'],
    'score': [10,8,9,9,0],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

new = pd.DataFrame()

for key, val in df.groupby('device'):
    data = val.groupby('category').mean().sort_values(by='score', ascending=False)
    print(data)
    s = pd.Series(data.index)
    s.name = key
    new = pd.concat([new, s], axis=1)
    
print(new)
```

Result:

```
  device    category  score
0      A      soccer     10
1      A  basketball      8
2      B  basketball      9
3      A      soccer      9
4      C       tenis      0

            score
category         
soccer        9.5
basketball    8.0

            score
category         
basketball    9.0

          score
category       
tenis       0.0

            A           B      C
0      soccer  basketball  tenis
1  basketball         NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy:

```
# Calculate the mean score per category and device type
tmp = df.pivot_table(
    index="category",
    columns="deviceType",
    values="score",
    aggfunc="mean",
)

# Extract the score and category matrix into numpy
score = tmp.to_numpy()
category = np.tile(tmp.index, (len(tmp.columns), 1)).T

# Sort the score descending. numpy always sort ascending so to do descending
# sort, we need to negate the `score` array
index = np.argsort(-score, axis=0)

# Sort score and category
ordered_score = np.take_along_axis(score, index, axis=0)
ordered_category = np.take_along_axis(category, index, axis=0)

# Result
pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(np.isnan(ordered_score), "", ordered_category), columns=tmp.columns
)
```

Another solution with pandas:

```
(
    # Calculate the mean score
    df.groupby(["deviceType", "category"], as_index=False)["score"]
    .mean()
    # Sort by the mean score despondingly and assign an order
    .sort_values("score", ascending=False)
    .assign(order=lambda x: x.groupby("deviceType").cumcount())
    # Pivot for final result
    .pivot_table(index="order", columns="deviceType", values="category", aggfunc="first")
)
```